# TeamSpeak Server Status and info

Tags: php, teamspeak

I have a teamspeak server and I would like to show the server status (online, offline)and the number of clients are connect in a webpage (in PHP). Could you help me please ?

I dont have serverquery my provider dont give it to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Provider won't give you **the** Query, but there is actually another Query, that you can use **only** for your "virtual" Server.

It is pretty simple, because everything you need, you already have.
I will just give you a Step Tutorial:

- Connect to your Teamspeak Server with your "Admin Identity"
- On the Top Menu click on "Tools" => "ServerQuery Login"
- In the appeared Window you type in your Queryname, like "php"
- Then it gives you a Password, and that's basicly it

After this simple steps you have a Query Login, **but** ask your Provider if he may whitelist your Webserver's IP to use it without limits!

You can use the Query Login as normal in PHP Scripts, like this:

```
# Include Teamspeak Framework
include "libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php";

# Connect to Server
$yourserver = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://php:PHKFokBB@127.0.0.1:10011/?nickname=Epic+PHP+Query&server_port=9988");
```

**Remember:** the Script is just an Example, not tested, that should be edited and worked into your Project.

**Reference:** [Teamspeak 3 PHP Framework](https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use google for "Teamspeak Server Status" you will find many sites already providing this tool for users. If you want your own custom tool Teamspeak provides some very nice information on their website.

Comment: Your provider should be able to give this to you. Send them a support ticket and request this information.

Comment: yes i send and they reply , he say, he cant give ther query because with tah i can delete other servers etc..